# Unity GUIText on Collision c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers, collision, guitext

I'm writing a 3D maze program in C# and I need to have UI Text display "You Win!" When the player reaches the end of the maze.

I have a trigger set up in Unity as a cube, named FinishLine, and I have the UI text named winText

I'm getting an error on this line..

GUI.Box(New rect (10,10,100,90), winText);

the error is "The best overloaded method matfch for unityengine.gui.box (unityEngine rect, string)' has some invalid arguments

I also have no idea what those numbers are (10,10,100,90), so maybe that's messing something up? What are those values indicating...?

Here is my code..

```
public class TextTrigger : MonoBehaviour {

     public GUIText winText;
     private bool FinishLine = false;

     void Start () {
         FinishLine = false;
     }

     void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col){
         if (col.tag == "Player") {
             FinishLine = true;   
         }
     }

     void OnGui() {
         GUI.Box(new Rect(10,10,100,90), winText);
     }
 }
```

EDIT - Updated my code, and I have a new error. 
On line 21 it says: *"UnityEngine.Texture does not contain a definition for text and no extension method 'text' accepting a first argument of type 'UnityEngine.Texture' could be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly refrence?*

NEW CODE:

> > using System.Collections; using System.Collections.Generic; using
> >     UnityEngine; using UnityEngine.UI;
> >
> > public class FinishLine : MonoBehaviour {
> >
> > ```
> > public Texture winText;     private bool FinishPlane = false;
> >
> > // Use this for initialization  void Start () {         FinishPlane =
> > ```
> >
> > false;
> >
> > ```
> > }
> >
> > void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)   {       if (col.tag == "Player") {
> >         FinishPlane = true;             winText.text = "You Win!";      }   } }
> > ```

Comment: You might want to check out [the Game Development SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) for questions related to the Unity engine or video game building related questions.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your error? Also, have you considered using the new Unity UI? It's a lot simpler to manage - you can just create a Text component on an object, then enable/disable it to display the text as needed like any other GameObject/component.

Comment: Opps, knew i was forgetting something. "The best overloaded method matfch for unityengine.gui.box (unityEngine rect, string)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is `OnGUI` not `OnGui`. The spelling counts. If you find yourself using `OnGUI`, stop and find other ways to accomplish whatever you are doing.

`GUIText` is a legacy UI Component. It's old and the `Text` component should now be used. If you still want to use it, below is the proper way to use `GUIText`.

```
public GUIText winText;
private bool FinishLine = false;

void Start()
{
    FinishLine = false;
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.tag == "Player")
    {
        FinishLine = true;
        winText.text = "You Win";
    }
}
```

---

`Text` component should be used for this and below is how to do that with the `Text` component:

```
public Text winText;
private bool FinishLine = false;

void Start()
{
    FinishLine = false;
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.tag == "Player")
    {
        FinishLine = true;
        winText.text = "You Win";
    }
}
```

You can learn more about Unity's new UI [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui).

Comment: Thank you Programmer! I watched a couple videos, trying to through the code in now and im running into one error on line 20 "unityEngine.Texture' does not contain a definition for 'text' and no extension method text accepting a first argument of type 'unityEngine.texture' could be found are you missing a directive or an assembly refrence?

Comment: Put **EDIT** in your question and post the new code that is causing the error. I will take a look at it. Also, you are supposed to have `using UnityEngine.UI;` at the top of the code.

Comment: It is `public Text winText;` not `public Texture winText;`. Please copy the code from the answer I left **directly**.

Comment: ahp. I fixed it right before i saw your comment. I knew it had to be something little, I'm using monodev and it automatically put texture when i tpyed text. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Nice. Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) answer if your problem is solved.

Comment: Lsat question, Should I have this script by it's self or add it into my PlayerControler? I have it by its self, and i connected it to my plane, and added theUI text into the Win Text spot in my inspector but it's not showing up when I collide with my object.

Comment: If text does not change then check if `OnTriggerEnter` is being called at-all. I suggest you ask a new question for this. Before you ask a question, put Debug.Log` in the `OnTriggerEnter` function then put another one inside the `if (col.tag == "Player")`. You can use this to figure out what the problem is. If you still can't then post a new question and tell us what the `Debug.Log` says.